# proud to or proud of: what is the best choice

Tags: gerunds

Shall I say  proud of doing virtually nothing or proud to do virtually nothing

I think  the first one sounds less idiomatic but I don't know why

Comment: why would you be proud of that?

Comment: Oh it is a translation in english of a  title from  a song of french punk band called Olivenstein very ironic

Comment: Your English translation is potentially ambiguous. It could mean "proud of the fact that one does nothing" or "there are no things that one is proud of doing." Which is the intended meaning (maybe post the original French?)

Comment: OK Here is the french title "fier de ne rien faire" ("Je suis fier de ne rien faire") may be" i do nothing but I am proud of that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "proud of doing virtually nothing sounds more present tense, whereas "proud to do virtually nothing sounds like something you are going to in the future. However I think they are definitely interchangeable. They both sound fine.

"Proud of" usually goes with a person or thing, like "I am proud of my daughter."Or "I am proud of John for standing up for her".

"Proud to" be more typically goes with a verb or adjective, like "I am proud to be a veteran." Or "I am proud to fly my flag."